# R3 imports cannot contain directives

Tags: java, osgi, fuseesb

I have a JBoss Fuse 6.0.0. server where I'd like to deploy an OSGI bundle contained in a jar. Upon deployment the server logs contain the following exception:

```
13:54:01,802 | INFO  | l Console Thread | Console                          | 15 - org.apache.karaf.shell.console - 2.3.0.redhat-60024 | Exception caught while executing command
org.apache.karaf.shell.console.MultiException: Error installing bundles:
    Unable to install bundle file:/tmp/my-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.MultiException.throwIf(MultiException.java:91)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.InstallBundle.doExecute(InstallBundle.java:70)[47:org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:38)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:176)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.DelayedStarted.run(DelayedStarted.java:61)[15:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to install bundle file:/tmp/my-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.InstallBundle.doExecute(InstallBundle.java:45)[47:org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: R3 imports cannot contain directives.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeImportClauses(ManifestParser.java:351)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.<init>(ManifestParser.java:163)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleRevisionImpl.<init>(BundleRevisionImpl.java:119)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.createRevision(BundleImpl.java:1199)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.<init>(BundleImpl.java:96)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:3080)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:165)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.InstallBundle.doExecute(InstallBundle.java:43)[47:org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi:2.3.0.redhat-60024]
    ... 11 more
```

The bundle manifest does not contain anything that I'd consider as a directive (though I might be mistaken):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: root
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_25
FAB-Provided-Dependency: org.apache.cxf:*
                            org.apache.camel:* 
                            [...SNIP...]
                            org.quartz:*
FAB-Version-Range-Digits: 0
Import-Package: bsh;resolution:="optional",
                                edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent;resolution:="optional",
                            [...SNIP...]
                            org.bouncycastle.util;resolution:="optional",                               
                            *
ProjectVersion: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
SVNRevisionNumber:
```

The Google results for the error message did not help that much. Could someone please help with clarifying or resolving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your manifest file is missing the entries:

```
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: .....
```

Without those your bundle is assumed to comply with the OSGi R3 specification, so `resolution:="optional"` is not valid. If you add those manifest entries the bundle will be treated as R4 compliant and should work.